# Can't set up Passport with Express and MongoDB/Mongoose - Sample Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm new to Node.js. Trying to set up user account creation and log in using Passport.

I chose Passport due to its popularity, however I can't seem to piece together a working authentication process based off of the documentation on the Passport site.

Does anyone know of a tutorial for setting this up? Preferably one where you can download the source code.

I'll share my app.js file, perhaps that will reveal what is lacking.

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , home = require('./routes/home')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  , flash = require('connect-flash');


var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(flash());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { 
        return done(err); 
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
  })
);
app.get('/home', home.dashboard);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Note: This code simply returns me to the root page when attempting to log in. I realize that I don't have any actual user accounts at this point, however I would like to at least get a successful log in with a fake user. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , home = require('./routes/home')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , mongodb = require('mongodb')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , path = require('path')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  , flash = require('connect-flash')
  ;

var app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('Connected to DB');
});
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function (password) {
  if (password === this.password) {
    return true; 
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var user = new User({ username: 'andrew', password: 'secret' });
user.save();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(flash());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { 
        return done(err); 
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
  })
);
app.get('/home', home.dashboard);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Also, thanks. I do feel compelled to mention, though, that you should not return that the user exists if the password is wrong; it's one of the many little things that compromise the security of web services.

Comment: @Romiox Depends. There are many websites where you can easily get a list of their users (like StackOverflow), and they're not less secure because of that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example using `passport-local` with `Express` as a part of the [passport-local source](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/express3). It may be helpful to set the `failureRedirect` of the `passport.authenticate` call to the `login` page and add the necessary code to your login view template to show flash messages, see the linked source. If you need more help, check out the source of the other passport modules.

It appears that the problem might be in the callback for the `LocalStrategy`. The `User` model does not appear to have been required.

Comment: Thanks Dixon. I'll check out their examples. There were a few issues with my code. Yes, the fact that the User model was missing was part of it. With some help in the Nodejitsu IRC chatroom I was able to get it working. I'll post below.